# Rails 6 metaタグ&OGP設定で投稿記事ごとに画像を取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

Rails 6 でmetaタグ&OGP設定によりサイトの投稿記事ページごとの画像を取得しようとしておりますが、できておりません。

取得するページのhtml.erb最上部に以下のコードを記述しています。
titleとdescriptionは取得できますが、imageだけが反映されず
application_helper.rbのimageを参照してしまいます。

```
<% set_meta_tags title: @article.title , description: @article.content1 , image: @article.picture1.url %>
```

また、以下のようにも記載してみましたが、やはりapplication_helper.rbの方を
参照してしまいます。

```
<% set_meta_tags title: @article.title , description: @article.content1 %>
<meta property="og:image" content= ”@article.picture1.url” >
```

やり方は下記リンク先の記事を参考にしています。

[Railsアプリでmetaタグ＆OGP設定をする方法](https://creat4869.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/15/170109)
[レシピページのOGP画像を動的に生成する](https://techlife.cookpad.com/entry/dynamic-og-image)

解決方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

meta-tags gem を利用した上で `set_meta_tags` を使い、キーワード引数として `image` を指定しても実際に出力される HTML の meta タグに指定した内容が出力されない、という質問だと理解しました。

まず meta-tags gem の `set_meta_tags` は `image` というキーワード引数を取りません。gem のドキュメントをご覧ください。おそらく `image_src` か `og` の中の `image` あたりと混同されているのではないかと思います: https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags#allowed-options-for-display_meta_tags-and-set_meta_tags-methods

たとえば og:image を指定するのであれば以下のようにするとできます。

```
set_meta_tags og: { image: "ここにURLを入れる" }
```